# restrict HTML input in textarea field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

`<%= f.text_area :body,:class=>"form-control",:placeholder=>"Your comments",:rows=>"5"%>`

I want to validate with `regex` for this field such that no user can input HTML contents in it.

Comment: Does adding `:pattern => '^(?=(?!.*<\/?\w+[^>]*>.*$)).*$'` help? Like `<%= f.text_area :body,:class=>"form-control",:placeholder=>"Your comments",:rows=>"5",:pattern => '^(?=(?!.*<\/?\w+[^>]*>.*$)).*$' %>`

Comment: Validate where? Before submitting to the controller (in the browser), before saving to the database (in the controller), before outputting to html (in the view) ?

Comment: Validate, before submitting to the controller

Answer (score 0):

There is a build-in method for escaping HTML and JS `escapeHTML` or its alias `h`. Please check out the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) for more information about XSS.

So, these methods can be used before saving information to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got `safe_join` helper method from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html. I used it in controller as:

`include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper`

`def create`
`@comment.body=safe_join([@comment.body])`